# How can i prevent double submission of <a href="">?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding the double submission.

I have a multiple `<a href = "">`.
I want to disables all the `<a href="">` if i click in one of the `<a href= "">`

Code:

```
<a href="dashboard.php" id ="submitID" class="submit" >Dashboard </a>
<a href="orderList.php"  id ="submitID" class="submit" >Order List</a>
<a href="newOrder.php"  id ="submitID" class ="submit">New Order</a>
```

Comment: IDs must be __unique__.

Comment: you should do such things on the server-side (too)
by using unique identifier or something similar

Comment: @cIph3r Why would there need to be anything done on the server?  There is no reason for that when this is simple client-side usability.  Move this type of functionality off of the server

Comment: because sometimes users turn off js at all. In this case, it's about double submissions, such things should be prevented at all. When it comes to things to ultimately prevent (such as form validation or security - or in this case, ordering) js is no solution. It can improve usability by doing those checks on the client side too, but always consider checking critical operations on the server-side

Comment: @cIph3r  If you are worried about that, remove the href from the anchors altogether and add them in your javascript.  This would be the unobtrusive practice.  Now, if you're truly worried about a double submission, by all means check server side.  However, these links (especially dashboard and orderList) don't seem to indicate that a double load would be too worrisome, and removing the links altogether from the href would be a good practice, especially if you want to pull them from an external config in a real test/preprod/prod environment

Answer (score 2):

First, please fix your `id`s to be unique.

If you're using jQuery versions 1.4.3+:

```
$("a.submit").click(function() {
    $("a.submit").bind('click', false);
});
```

If not, bind `function() { return false; }`. Then you can also

```
$("a.submit").unbind('click')
```

when you want them to work again.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

First of all, you should never have multiple DOM elements with the same ID.

Second of all, set a variable in a bind to the submit class (the bind is using jquery), and flip it if you submit.

Include jquery with a script tag and then wrap your javascript in document ready

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.submit').bind('click', function () {
        var isSubmitted = false;
        if (isSubmitted === false) {
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function () {
                isSubmitted = true;
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is of course assuming you want some ajax style functionality.  If not, you shouldn't really be worried if you have a link since you'd be posting to a new page

Comment: @user2167887  My code is dependent on two things (which I probably should have included at the beginning...my apologies.  I have updated my code to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
var count=0;
$(".submit").click(function(){
if(count>0){
return false
}
++count;
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="dashboard.php" id ="submitID1" class="submit" >Dashboard </a>

<a href="orderList.php"  id ="submitID2" class="submit" >Order List</a>    

<a href="newOrder.php"  id ="submitID3" class ="submit">New Order</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var submitStatus = false;
    $('a.submit').click(function(e){
        if (!submitStatus) {
            alert('clicked');
            submitStatus = true;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/p8a5s/
And don`t use the same ID`s for different DOM elements, of course

Comment: Thank You :)) Your the best @Glen Swift